# Why compiler is showing unexpected result?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new in programming. At current learning C language.I'm confused right now in a problem which is showing unexpected result after running.

The problem is-

I want to make a program which take input one more than when the user input `42` and stop taking input after it and print all the numbers user had typed before `42` has come.

For example-**Input:**

```
1
2
88
42
99
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
88
```

**My Program-**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1, j, temp;

    printf("enter numbers:\n");
    while (i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        i++;

        int a[i];

        a[i - 2] = temp;
        if (temp == 42)
        {
            scanf("%d", &a[i - 1]);
            for (j = 0 ; j < i - 1 ; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] == 42)
                    break;
                else 
                    printf("%d\n",a[j]);
            }        
        }
        if (temp == 42)
            break;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

When i input the same value as in example i get unexpected result such as-

```
4196363
0
-1
```

Please help.And sorry for my bad english.Thankyou in advance.

Comment: always check the returned value (not the parameter value) from scanf() to assure the operation was successful

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code, for instance [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31494659/why-compiler-is-showing-unexpected-result#comment50952802_31494659) and it's completely unreadable.

Comment: I don't understand what logic you used in your code. Please use comments in your code to clarify.

Comment: Try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).  I suspect you'll discover that there are several fundamental concepts you don't quite have a handle on yet and should learn more about.  For example, try explaining to the imaginary duck what the lines `int a[i];` and `a[i-2] = temp;` are supposed to do.

Comment: Please indent the code consistently.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  For readability, separate code blocks by a blank line.   Never use tabs for indenting because each editor/wordprocessor has the tab stops/tab width set differently

Comment: Sorry i'm going to edit the program .

Comment: the method of declaring a[] is not correct.   Suggest just declare once: 'int * a = NULL;'   then use 'i' to track where to place next value from user.  before placing a value into a[], int tPointer = malloc( (i+1)* sizeof(int))  then if( NULL == tPointer) {//handle malloc failure} else { a = tPointer; a[i] =  temp; i++;}   incorporate into this the check for 42

Comment: why print the whole array: a[] each time a new value is entered?  might be better to enter values until 42 entered, then exit the 'enter values' loop, enter a simple loop that prints all the values, so they are only printed once and do not clutter the screen where the user is trying to enter values.  Probably should inform the user that 42 is the flag to stop entering values as part of the initial printf statement

Comment: I want to make a program which take input one more than when the user input 42.

Comment: You might want to know that the compiler is not showing the incorrect result.  Rather the program, after being successfully compiled, is showing the incorrect result.

Comment: @user3629249 It's unexpected rather than incorrect. It's correct.

Comment: Are you talking abut this problem? --SPOJ - Life, the Universe, and Everything

Comment: This is a SPOJ question. The simple correct answer to the SPOJ problem has been deleted (I missed any comments) but presumably since it is unhelpful to solve the SPOJ problem itself. @iharob made a brave attempt to sort out OP's tangle, but even then the answer will be rejected, since the output will still contain the text `"enter numbers:\n"` which will cause the answer to fail, since it was not part of the example output given.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing uninitialized values because if `i`'s value becomes `3` and greater values after that you never set `a[0]` as well as all the values before `a[i - 2]`.

Thus causing [Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) at the following line

```
printf("%d\n", a[j]);
```

some values are uninitialized and you still try to print them.

You should notice that `a` is being redeclared at each iteration and you are not initializing the values because the values in the previous `a` where only valid in the previous iteration.

The `a` variable is valid only within the scope of the `while` loop but not only because it's not declared outside, also because it's deallocated when it becomes out of scope. Perhaps an example will make it clearer.

Suppose you had the following program

```
int main(void)
{
    int *pointer = NULL;
    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        pointer = array;
    }
    /* `poitner' points to `array` but array was deallocated */
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", pointer[i]); /* This is UB */
    return 0;
}
```

this would compile, however as you can see it will invokes undefined behavior.

Since it's not possible to understand what your code does, I suggest the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int a[100];

    printf("enter numbers:\n");
    while (i++ < 100)
    {
        if (scanf("%d%*c", &a[i - 2]) != 1)
            return -1; /* this was invalid input, it will cause UB */
        if (a[i - 2] == 42)
        {
            if (scanf("%d%*c", &a[i - 1]) != 1)
                return -1; /* this was invalid input, it will cause UB */
            for (int j = 0 ; j < i - 1 ; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] == 42)
                    break;
                else
                    printf("%d\n", a[j]);
            }
        }

        if (a[i - 2] == 42)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This at least removes undefiend behavior and meakes teh code more readable, but it's still not clear what is this program for or what it should do.

Comment: i think `a[i-2]` is correct as it will assign the value of temp in i-2 element. @iharob

Comment: for example if my first input is 2 then `i=2` and `a[i-2]=2` i.e `a[0]=2`

Comment: What if `i == 3`? `a[1]` is probably initialized if `scanf()` didn't fail, and `a[2]` as well, but you leave `a[0]` uninitialized and still print it in `printf("%d\n", a[j]);` that's undefined behavior.

Comment: i know that will be undefined before .Check my above comment please.

Comment: I am certain that this answer is correct, this is the problem in the original code, whether the code I posted is useful or not doesn't matter, it's just an example of how to avoid UB, the [DOWNVOTER](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) doesn't like me :).

Comment: i think i[0] will be equal to the first enterd number.

Comment: @user3788135 It will not, see the update to my answer and you may understand why!

Answer (score 0):

In general case because the number of entered values is unknown you need to allocate dynamically storage for a new entered value.

So I would build a list that contains entered values. The other approach as to use `malloc` and `realloc` for the whole array when a new value is entered. In my opinion it is a worse solution than to build a list.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    struct node
    {
        int value;
        struct node *next;
    } * head = NULL;

    struct node **current = &head;
    int value;

    int next = -1;

    while ( next != 1 && scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 )
    {
        if ( next == 0 || value == 42 ) ++next;

        if ( next == -1 )
        {            
            *current = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
            ( *current )->value = value;
            ( *current )->next  = NULL;
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }

    while ( head )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", head->value );
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( tmp );
    }        
}
```

If to enter for example the following values

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 42 10
```

then the program output will be

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The list stores neither 42 nor the next value after 42 though you can modify the program such a way that it would store also these values.

As for your code then at least this statement

```
   a[i - 2] = temp;
```

is wrong when i is equal to 1 and results in undefined behaviour of the program.
And I do not see that i would be changed.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing some unnecessary matter.
You have to check just this--

```
while(input_number)
{
    if(input_number==42)
      break;
    else
      printf("%d\n",input_number);
}
```

In my thought I had edited your code to store all number before `42` based on your code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=1,j,temp;
    int a[10010];
    printf("enter numbers:\n");
    while(i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        i++;
        a[i-2]=temp;
        if(temp==42)
        {
            for(j=0; j<i-2; j++)
            {
                if(a[j]==42)
                    break;
                else
                    printf("%d\n",a[j]);
            }

        }
        if (temp == 42)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why exactly 10010? How did you come up with that number?

Comment: Yes but that's a very particular size.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is trying to declare(and redeclare) a[i] multiple times with different values. The compiler needs to know the size of an array at compile time.  So the compiler is setting aside memory for an integer array with one element and then the dynamic part of your code is attempting to redeclare it a run-time.  Try moving a outside the while loop and declaring it with a well defined maximum number of integer values like:

```
#define MAX_NUMS 1000

int a[MAX_NUMS];
```

There are some other problems as listed above, but I tested this with GCC 4.9 compiler and it seems to give the desired result.

Comment: what if i don't how many time the user wants to enter values?

Comment: one of the big problems with using the old C libraries is just that.  The C++ STL defines dynamic containers like vector that can be changed at runtime.  You could possibly malloc() whenever you need more space, though I've never seen that done. Usually when you malloc it is already known exactly how much memory you need.